# 100 Dice Rolls - Market Making Game

Tags: expected-value, game-theory

Say I roll $100$ dice. Make a market on the sum of all the dice.

**How does one go about approaching these types of problems?** Here's my approach:

I expect the sum to be $350$, so this is where my market will be centered around. The variance of a dice roll is $2.9$, so in total, I expect the variance to be $290$. Square root of this is around $17$, so that is $1$SD. I'll make my market centered be $2$SD wide on each side, so I'll make my market be $[350-(17)2, 350+(17)2]$.

**Another question: Why wouldn't I just make the lower end of the market equal to 0, so that I can buy it for even $0?**

Comment: Do you mean, you want to price the asset that is the outcome of the die roll? So if you roll 100 dice, you might get a monetary payout of any value between 100 dollars and 600 dollars, with an expectation of 350 dollars? Also, the variance satisfies $\mathbb{V}(aX) = a^2 \mathbb{V}(X)$, not $\mathbb{V}(aX) = a \mathbb{V}(X)$.

Comment: And yes, making a market is like giving a bid/ask spread, and you want to maximize your payout, while being smart about your bounds. The true value of the asset is 350, so I would make money by buying for a lower price, or selling for a higher price.

Comment: Oh shoot, so the variance would be 2.9 * 100^2? And thus, the SD would be 170?

Comment: OK, so the risk neutral value of the asset is 350 dollars, but what someone else is willing to pay you to buy the asset depends on their risk aversion. Typically, people value risk as $\mathbb{E}[u(X)]$, where $u(x)$ is concave and increasing, so that by Jensen's inequality, $u(\mathbb{E}[X]) \ge \mathbb{E}[u(X)]$, which is where the risk premium comes from. So the question is, who is in your market? How much are they willing to pay, etc.

Comment: Okay let me think about this. Also, can you verify for me real quick if the variance is then 2.9*100 or 2.9* 100^2? Because 2.9*100^2 is just such a huge, unrealistic number.

Comment: You can verify it by calculating it, or just look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties

Comment: You would probably like the binomial asset pricing model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_options_pricing_model)  It's based on lots of coin flips and is the first step to black-scholes.

Comment: You cant make it 0 cuz the interviewer wants you to simulate an actual market making session. If you quote your bid as 0, no one in the real world will ever sell to you and thus you wont be able to buy. The interviewer wants to see how well you can simulate a real order flow.

Comment: When u make your market 2 S.D. wide, you are giving a 95% confidence interval so it depends on whether you would like to further narrow the bid/ask spread or not.